Why isn't my code which is supposed to target and turn towards player not working? I filled in all variables btw
my problem is that it knows to turn because I added a debug.log statement but it still will not turn even though I have the quaternion.RotateTowards function.
At first I tried to replace the Quaternion.RotateTowards with transform.Rotation which worked but it was an instant rotation. I have a feeling you could use lerping but im not sure how to use lerp. Here is my code:
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class missileScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player;
    public float moveSpeed = 2f;
    public float turnSpeed = -30f; // Turn speed in degrees per second
    private float distanceToPlayer;
    private float moveX;
    private float moveY;
    public float turnQuaternionSpeed;
    void Start()
    {
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        distanceToPlayer = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, transform.position);
        if (distanceToPlayer < 8.58f)
        {
            fire();
        }
    }

    void fire()
    {
        float direction = player.position.y - transform.position.y;
        // Ensure direction is not zero to prevent division by zero
        if (direction !=0.5)
        {
            direction = direction / Mathf.Abs(direction); // Normalize direction to -1 or 1
            Debug.Log(direction);
            float currentZRotation = transform.rotation.z;
            float targetZRotation = currentZRotation + (direction * turnSpeed);

            Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, targetZRotation);

            // Use RotateTowards for smoother rotation
            Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, turnQuaternionSpeed);

            // Calculate movement direction
            float rotationInRadians = transform.eulerAngles.z * Mathf.Deg2Rad;
            moveY = Mathf.Sin(rotationInRadians);
            moveX = Mathf.Cos(rotationInRadians);
            Vector2 moveDirection = new Vector2(-moveX, -moveY).normalized * moveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

            transform.Translate(moveDirection, Space.World);
            
        }
    }




}


Some general points: what is the != 0.5f check supposed to do exactly? Die to floating point precision this is probably always true anyway ... For Normalize direction to -1 or 1 you know there is Mathf.Sign ;)

You also never actually use the return value of Quaternion.RotateTowards .. and you apply two times a smoothing speed .. first when you calculate the target rotation and then again in RotateTowards

Finally if this is Physics related you should go through the Rigidbody component instead of Transform .. otherwise you probably shouldn't be doing this in FixedUpdate but Update

I don't quite get your calculation for the target rotation.
But first of all note that a rotation is a Quaternion with not 3 but 4 components x, y, z, w moving in the ranges -1 to 1. So
float currentZRotation = transform.rotation.z;

is definitely not something you want to access in most of use cases.
for getting the rotation on the Z axis there are a couple of ways - if you never rotate around any other the easiest would be to check against the global up vector and do e.g.
float currentZRotation = Vector3.SignedAngle(Vector3.up, transform.up);

Another way might be going through Euler space and do
float currentZRotation = transform.eulerAngles.z;

Note though

When you read the .eulerAngles property, Unity converts the Quaternion's internal representation of the rotation to Euler angles. Because, there is more than one way to represent any given rotation using Euler angles, the values you read back out may be quite different from the values you assigned. This can cause confusion if you are trying to gradually increment the values to produce animation.
To avoid these kinds of problems, the recommended way to work with rotations is to avoid relying on consistent results when reading .eulerAngles particularly when attempting to gradually increment a rotation to produce animation. For better ways to achieve this, see the Quaternion * operator.


So all the other comments I left on the question aside - you could probably simplify this quite a lot and do something like
// Get direction as actual vector
var direction = player.position - transform.position;
// Eliminate depth -> vector only in XY plane
var direction.z = 0;

// A rotation that rotates from UP to your current rotation
// -> a rotation around Z axis
var targetRotation = Quaternion.FromToRotation(Vector3.up, direction);

// Actually use and apply the result
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, turnQuaternionSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

See also

Quaternion.FromToRotation

